# (1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php (line 251) - Error Occur After I Approve or Decline a Donation

Tags: laravel

this is my controller for approving and declining a donation

```
    public function postApprove($id)
{
   $application=DB::table('donationdetails')->where('DonationDetailsId','=',$id)->first();



     $application->DonationStatus='Approved';
     $application->update();

     return redirect('/viewdonation');

}



public function postReject($id)
{
    $application=DB::table('donationdetails')->where('DonationDetailsId','=',$id)->first();
 // $application=Application::where('id','=',$id)->first();
      if($application){

        $application->approved=false;
         $application->update();
         dd($application);

      return redirect()->back()->with('error','The application was disapproved successfully');

  }
}
```

This is my blade, where i manipulate the donation.

```
<tbody>
        @foreach($donation as $donation)
        <br>
        <br>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $donation->DonationId }}</td>
                <td>{{ $donation->AttrName }}</td>
                <td>{{ $donation->AttrType }}</td>
                <td>{{ $donation->AttrSize }}</td>
                <td>{{ $donation->ItemImage }}</td>
                <td>{{ $donation->ItemQuantity }}</td>
                <td>{{ $donation-> DonationDate }}</td>
                <td>{{ $donation->DeliveryType }}</td>
                <td>{{ $donation-> DonationStatus }}</td>

             <form method="POST">
                 <td><a  href="{{route('approveDonation',['id'=>$donation->DonationDetailsId])}}" class="btn btn-info" id="myForm">Approve</a></td>
                  <td><a  href="{{route('rejectDonation',['id'=>$donation->DonationDetailsId])}}" class="btn btn-info" id="myForm">decline</a></td>
             </form>

        @endforeach
            </tr>
    </tbody>
```

here is my Route

```
Route::post('/viewdonation/approve/{id}','ViewDonationController@postApprove')->name("approveDonation");

Route::post('/viewdonation/reject/{id}','ViewDonationController@postReject')->name("rejectDonation");
```

---

HI guys I need a help. After i run my code, it will return an error

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong. (1/1)
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php (line 251)

I can't figure out which line of code is Wrong. can you please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Try changing the route method to GET instead of POST. If you want to use POST method then make sure you have submit button in the form

Comment: Can u run this command and show the output  php artisan route:list

Comment: php artisan route:list

Comment: php artisan route:clear , composer dump-autoload ,

Answer (score 0):

I think you fired wrong URL in your browser which doesn't match any of your routes in routes.php

Comment: i think I didn't fired a wrong URL. It is the same on what I link in my buttons and in my route and i can get the ID of the Item I wish to approve to. Do have any suggestion or ways to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You get this error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` because you are trying to request a url with POST method using a GET request. An anchor tag will always send a GET request unless you modify it with JS, I guess. Try changing your routes to :

```
Route::get('/viewdonation/approve/{id}','ViewDonationController@postApprove')->name("approveDonation");
Route::get('/viewdonation/reject/{id}','ViewDonationController@postReject')->name("rejectDonation");
```

Sorry for my English, hope it helps.

Comment: I tried it but it returns an error (1/1) ErrorException
Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\ViewDonationController::postApprove()

Comment: Okay, it seems like your controller require a parameter (`$id`), did you get the id value in the route ?